# Binarization using pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie to the world of ML. I am trying to learn to preprocess.

I have an outcome data that has four types of inputs: 0,1,2,3,4

0 corresponds to no disease while 1 to 4 corresponds to different types of diseases.

I wish to binarize them into two: 0 for "no disease" and those 1-4 "with diseases"

My code:

```
binarize_outcome['Outcome']=pd.cut(outcome_variable['Outcome'], bins=[0,1,4], labels=["no heart disease","heart diseases"])
binarize_outcome
```

The output:

```
0                                                        NaN
1                                           no heart disease
2                                           no heart disease
3                                                        NaN
4                                                        NaN
                                 ...                        

299                                         no heart disease
300                                         no heart disease
301                                         no heart disease
302                                                      NaN
Outcome    0                   NaN
1        heart disease...
Name: Outcome, Length: 304, dtype: object
```

As you can see, it is not the output I am expecting because my code is labeling the 0s as NaN and the rest are incorrectly labeled.

Hope you can help me figure out this part.

Thanks in advance,
Art

Comment: Hm might be a index alignment problem. You have `binarize_outcome` on one side and `outcome_variable` on another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is binary so you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df
    Type
0      2
1      2
2      3
3      0
4      2
..   ...
95     2
96     4
97     0
98     0
99     1

[100 rows x 2 columns]

>>> df["Outcome"] = np.where(df == 0, "no heart disease", "heart disease")
>>> df
    Type           Outcome
0      2     heart disease
1      2     heart disease
2      3     heart disease
3      0  no heart disease
4      2     heart disease
..   ...               ...
95     2     heart disease
96     4     heart disease
97     0  no heart disease
98     0  no heart disease
99     1     heart disease

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) from `pandas`:

```
>>> df["Outcome"] = pd.cut(df["Type"], [0, 0.9999999, 4],
                           labels=["no heart disease", "heart disease"],
                           include_lowest=True)
>>> df
    Type           Outcome
0      2     heart disease
1      2     heart disease
2      3     heart disease
3      0  no heart disease
4      2     heart disease
..   ...               ...
95     2     heart disease
96     4     heart disease
97     0  no heart disease
98     0  no heart disease
99     1     heart disease

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Same result with [`pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_breaks.html):

```
>>> interval = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([0, 1, 5], closed="left")
>>> df["Outcome"] = pd.cut(df["Type"], interval, include_lowest=True) \
                      .cat.rename_categories(["no heart disease", "heart disease"])
```